# WildFly 10.0.0 RBAC Custom roles

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, rbac

In my project I need to create custom role for WildFly Management as the roles that are predefined are not enough for me. We are using WildFly 10.0.0 in standalone mode (using standalone-full.xml configuration file). Server is running on CentOS Linux 7.

What I need to make is to allow a certain role to manage configuration (e.g. changing logging level) but managing deployments should be restricted. So far I have enabled rbac on server and tried different roles but none of them meets my requirements. I have digged a little bit in the internet and have not found any solution yet. So my question is is there any way to achieve this with the current state (standalone mode, no LDAP)? And if yes, how to do this?

Comment: The following videos may help you http://wildfly.org/news/2013/11/07/Role-Based-Access-Control-in-WildFly-8/

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly supply two way to authrioze, simple and rbac and deafult is simple, so if you want to use rbac, firstly you should configure some role on simple mode, then swith rbac, otherwise you will not login wildfy management web ui:

Bellow is my example configure:

```
 <access-control provider="rbac">
        <role-mapping>
            <role name="SuperUser">
                <include>
                    <user name="$local"/>
                </include>
            </role>
            <role name="Administrator">
                <include>
                    <user realm="ManagementRealm" name="admin"/>
                    <user realm="ApplicationRealm" name="sample"/>
                </include>
            </role>
            <role name="Auditor"/>
            <role name="Monitor"/>
            <role name="Operator"/>
            <role name="Deployer">
                <include>
                    <group realm="ApplicationRealm" name="common"/>
                    <user realm="ApplicationRealm" name="sample"/>
                    <user realm="ManagementRealm" name="deployer"/>
                </include>
            </role>
        </role-mapping>
    </access-control>
```

you can configure role at management ui: "Access Control" tab
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7nJF.png)

Notice: Please make sure, you have added user by "user-add.sh"

Comment: Yes, I know about Access Control and my question was if it is possible to create a "custom" role, what means that I would create new roles with only choosen by me privileges.